# adding objects to array in localStorage

Tags: javascript, local-storage

Ok, I've tried to follow examples here, I know there might be a few different ways of adding objects to an array in localstorage and not overwriting it but I'm failing to find at least one of them.

Got this code to store objects in array but it's overwriting itself. May anyone show me what am I missing? (And I'm afraid I could be missing a lot).

```
function addEntry() {
    var entryTitle = document.getElementById("entryTitle").value;
    var entryText = document.getElementById("entryText").value;
    var entry = {
        "title": entryTitle,
        "text": entryText
    };
    localStorage.setItem("entry", JSON.stringify(entry));
    var allEntries = [];
    allEntries.push(entry);
    localStorage.setItem("allEntries", JSON.stringify(allEntries));
};
```

Comment: Of course it's overwriting itself you're setting the value in the localstorage to a new array you just pushed something to. Where are you getting what's currently stored from the localStorage?

Comment: Please explain "it's overwriting itself" and what you are trying to accomplish with your code.

Answer (score 46):

When you use `setItem` it overwrites the item which was there before it. You need to use `getItem` to retrieve the old list, append to it, then save it back to localStorage:

```
function addEntry() {
    // Parse any JSON previously stored in allEntries
    var existingEntries = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("allEntries"));
    if(existingEntries == null) existingEntries = [];
    var entryTitle = document.getElementById("entryTitle").value;
    var entryText = document.getElementById("entryText").value;
    var entry = {
        "title": entryTitle,
        "text": entryText
    };
    localStorage.setItem("entry", JSON.stringify(entry));
    // Save allEntries back to local storage
    existingEntries.push(entry);
    localStorage.setItem("allEntries", JSON.stringify(existingEntries));
};
```

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Bxn2t/1/) which demonstrates the above.

Answer (score 13):

Maybe you just need to fetch the entries before pushing the new one:

```
var allEntries = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("allEntries")) || [];
allEntries.push(entry); 
//etc...
```

Answer (score 2):

**adding objects to array in localStorage (Ionic):**

```
var existingEntries = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("allEntries"));
if(existingEntries == null) existingEntries = [];
var testObject ={username:this.username, 
mobile:this.mobile,
email:this.email,
type:this.type,
password:this.password};

localStorage.setItem('testObject', JSON.stringify(testObject));
existingEntries.push(testObject);
localStorage.setItem("allEntries", JSON.stringify(existingEntries));
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
const object = {
name: 'ayyan',
age: 29,
number: 03070084689,
};
const arr = JSON.parse(localstorage.getItem('key_name')) || [];
arr.push(object);
localstorage.setItem(JSON.stringify('key_name', arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML5 localStorage lets you store key/value pairs of data. **Both key and value needs to be a string**. To store arrays as a key or value you need to encode the array into a JSON string. And while retrieving you need to decode it back to an array.

```
const object = {
name: 'ayyan',
age: 29,
number: 03070084689,
};
const arr = JSON.parse(localstorage.getItem('key_name')) || [];
const data = [arr, ...[object]];
localstorage.setitem(JSON.stringify('key', data);
```