# how to add objects to array in localStorage

Tags: javascript, python, html

I tried the solution posted on this [[adding objects to array in localStorage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19635077/adding-objects-to-array-in-localstorage/][1]) but it doesnt seem to work for me.Mine has a small change,I am getting the values as a list from python flask app:

```
    var myValue = {{ List|safe }};
    onload=function appendRow() {
    var names = [];
    names = myValue;
    var existingEntries = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("allEntries")) || [];
    localStorage.setItem("oltbl", JSON.stringify(names));
    existingEntries.push(oltbl);
    localStorage.setItem("allEntries", JSON.stringify(existingEntries))
    var storedNames = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("allEntries"));
    var tbl = document.getElementById('mixed'), 
    row = tbl.insertRow(tbl.rows.length),     
    i;
    for (i = 0; i < tbl.rows[0].cells.length; i++) {
    createCell(row.insertCell(i), storedNames[i], 'row');
     }
     }

    function createCell(cell, text, style) {
    var div = document.createElement('div'), 
    txt = document.createTextNode(text); 
    div.appendChild(txt);                    
    cell.appendChild(div);                  
    }
    </script>
    <body>
    <table id="mixed">
    <tr>
    <th>Title</th>
    <th>Text</th>
    <th>STATUS</th>
    </tr>
```

Any pointers?

Comment: what happens? do you get any errors?

Comment: I dont get any output in the table,the table is empty

Comment: when I have just this:

localStorage.setItem("oltbl", JSON.stringify(names));
    var storedNames = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("oltbl"));

It rewrites evrytime the function gets called.
I want to maintain a table everytime this page is rendered.

Comment: it should be `var storedNames = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("allEntries"));` instead of `var storedNames = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("oltbl"));` and `oltbl` is not defined, so you push nothing into your array

Comment: @oliv37 I have it like "JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("allEntries"))" in my code,this was done just for testing purpose.

Comment: the variable `oltbl` is not defined, so `existingEntries.push(oltbl);` will push nothing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're always setting the `allEntries` the result of itself, but since you never set a thing to it, it's blank

You should rethink what exactly what you want to achieve.

also

```
existingEntries.push(oltbl); /*oltbl IS NOT ASSIGNED*/
```

and causes js error

Comment: Ok,Can I have  it set as an array

        var oltbl=[];
        localStorage.setItem("oltbl", JSON.stringify(names));
This prints out [object Object] in the html page.

Basically I need to add entries of some values returned by flask app in the table without overwriting.

Comment: So you need to update your `allEntries` adding some new values?

Comment: yes each time new values get added to the array

Ive removed allEntries and tried printing the existingEntries array and this is what i got:

        localStorage.setItem("entry", JSON.stringify(entry));
        existingEntries.push(entry);
        document.getElementById('whereToPrint').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(existingEntries);
        var retrievedData = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("existingEntries"));
        document.getElementById('whereToPrint1').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(retrievedData);

existingEntries array gets printed,but retrievedData prints null.any idea why?

Comment: check your local storage using the chrome inspector window for example. open it (F12) > Application > Local Storage and see if you have what you expect

Comment: Hi Daniel, I am able to see the entries getting populated in LocalStorage->allEntries but when printing on html page it just shows up like this []

Comment: that's good! so we know that we have a problem just showing them, I did like this: `JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("oltbl"));` and it worked, give it a try ;)

Comment: Thanks Daniel! that was the issue,also the way i was iterating over the loop was incorrect:

        var retrievedData = localStorage.getItem("allEntries");
        var JsonObject = JSON.parse(retrievedData);
        for(var i = 0; i < JsonObject.length; i++) {
        var title = JsonObject[i].title;
        var text = JsonObject[i].text;
        var status = JsonObject[i].status;