# Objects are not pushing into Local Storage Array

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, local-storage

Help Me! I'm setting an array of objects into Local Storage. problem I'm having is that whenever I push new Object it removes the last object and stores the new one and array updates with new one. and keeps just single object. but I want to set multiple objects in array. I can't find what I'm doing wrong.

```
    let recent_searched = [];
    let searched_item = {}
    
    const storeLocal = (e) => {
            searched_item['artwork'] = "image.jpg"
            searched_item['itemName'] = "Harry Potter"
            searched_item['itemWriterName'] = "J K Rowling"

            recent_searched.push(searched_item)

            localStorage.setItem("recent_searched", JSON.stringify(recent_searched));
     }
```

```
    console.log(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("recent_searched")))
```

Comment: Assign `recent_searched` to `JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("recent_searched"))` instead of `[]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code only creates *one* plain object. It is defined with `let searched_item = {}`. The rest of your code only *mutates* that single object, even when it is already present in the array. And so you just append duplicate object references to your array.

You need to create a separate object each time you push it to the array. So:

```
let recent_searched = [];

const storeLocal = (e) => {
    let searched_item = {   // This creates(!) an object
        artwork: "image.jpg",
        itemName: "Harry Potter",
        itemWriterName: "J K Rowling"
    };
    recent_searched.push(searched_item)

    localStorage.setItem("recent_searched", JSON.stringify(recent_searched));
}
```

If your page reloads, then be aware that your array variable is not maintained and created from scratch. So make sure when the page loads, you *read* the contents from local storage:

```
let stored = localStorage.getItem("recent_searched");
let recent_searched = stored ? JSON.parse(stored) : [];
```

Comment: Creating a new object, or assigning properties to an existing one, this still doesn't append it to the existing array from local storage.

Comment: It appends it to the array `recent_searched`, and then writes that (extended) array as JSON to local storage, which I believe is exactly what the OP wants.

Comment: `it removes the last object and stores the new one and array updates with new one. and keeps just single object. but I want to set multiple objects in array.`

It sounds like they want `recent_searched` to contain the latest value from local storage.

Comment: @AustinBrunkhorst I want all objects as keep adding on. array should update like we push the object into it.

Comment: In case there is confusion on how to *read* the array from storage after the page reloads, I have added a paragraph about that.

Answer (score -1):

localStorage.setItem works like a replace function, it'll try to add a the value passed for the provided key, if the key already exists in localstorage, then it'll replace the older value with the new one.

you need to get older value and append your new values to it before saving.

Something like this

```
    let recent_searched = [];
    let searched_item = {};
    const data = await localStorage.getItem("recent_searched");
    if(data){
         recent_searched = JSON.parse(data);
    }
    searched_item['artwork'] = "image.jpg"
    searched_item['itemName'] = "Harry Potter"
    searched_item['itemWriterName'] = "J K Rowling"
    
    recent_searched.push(searched_item)
    
    localStorage.setItem("recent_searched", JSON.stringify(recent_searched));
```

Comment: It's returning null don't know why.

Comment: I've updated the code snippet, check if it works for you

Comment: it's giving an error. `Invalid attempt to spread non-iterable instance.
In order to be iterable, non-array objects must have a [Symbol.iterator]() method.`

Comment: and if I remove spreader.. then it goes back to null

Comment: I've done it by [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19635077/adding-objects-to-array-in-localstorage). still Thanks for helping out.